# Azure load balancer hosts status

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer

How to get the status of hosts failed health probes on azure load balancer? I got to see f Albert about ailed health probe but not say which host failed the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, for Basic and Standard SKU LB, you could use **health probe logs** to view problems detected by your health probe such as the number of instances in your backend-pool that are not receiving requests from the load balancer because of health probe failures by checking the `dipDownCount` property in the logs.

For standard SKU LB, you could view the multi-dimensional metrics including byte and packet counters, health probe status, connection attempts (TCP SYN), outbound connection health (SNAT successful and failed flows), active data plane measurements in the Azure monitoring. You could view these metric descriptions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-standard-diagnostics#multi-dimensional-metrics).

Except above all, it's not clear to show which host fails when the probe is failing. You may upvote [this feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/33300562-load-balancers-should-clearly-show-when-probes-are) to improve it. Hope this could help you.